# RUUD Package Unit Inducer shuts off after 3 seconds

Tags: hvac

When calling for heat from the thermostat, the inducer motor and blower motor both turn on.  The inducer motor then shuts off after about 3 seconds.  Have tried jumping the pressure switch.  I don't believe the blower motor used to come on at the same time the inducer does.  I can't see the ignitor heating up or hear the gas valve click which I wouldn't expect as the inducer is supposed to run for 15 seconds before ignition.  Anyone have thoughts on what to check next?

Comment: What model is the package unit?

Comment: I believe it is a UKKA-A060JK13E.